# Problem with callas preflight open flight error

Tags: preflight

I am using callas software integrated with .net, and it is working.
However, sometimes I get this error "ErrorPreflightOpenFileErr" or "PTB_eerrPreflightOpenFileErr" when I call callas with a pdf file.

By the error it seems as the file is there but is inaccessible.
There is a possibility we run the callas profiles while the file is still generating.
My thoughts are that some thread somewhere is copying the file or still generating the pdf and so when callas tries to access it, it fails.

Any thoughts on why? Is there a specific solution for this problem or is the thread thing a possible cause?

So far I couldn't really replicate it locally since it only keeps happening in production due to the volume of requests.